# JFreeChart XYPlot time series y value that intersects x

Tags: jfreechart, timeserieschart

I have a time series chart that has data plotted for each day, however not all days have data. In this scenario, how can I determine/calculate the y value for a given date. For example, in this chart, how can I calculate the y coordinate where x is 01-Mar-2016?

[image: chart]

I had a look at a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969188/how-to-get-y-value-from-x-value-in-jfreechart), but I couldn't apply it to the above requirement.

Comment: Have you tried [_interpolation_](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A230513+%5Bjfreechart%5D+interpolation)?

Answer (score 0):

The thread mentioned above was actually what I needed with a few tweaks for TimeSeries. Here is the code:

```
private static double interpolate(TimeSeries s, long x)
{
  List<?> items = s.getItems();
  for (int i=0; i<items.size()-1; i++)
  {
    TimeSeriesDataItem i0 = (TimeSeriesDataItem) items.get(i);
    TimeSeriesDataItem i1 = (TimeSeriesDataItem) items.get(i+1);
    long x0 = i0.getPeriod().getFirstMillisecond();
    double y0 = i0.getValue().doubleValue();
    long x1 = i1.getPeriod().getFirstMillisecond();
    double y1 = i1.getValue().doubleValue();

    if (x >= x0 && x <= x1)
    {
      double d = x - x0;
      double a = d / (x1-x0);
      double y = y0 + a * (y1 - y0);
      return y;
    }
 }

 // Should never happen
 return 0;
```

}